# Is it bad practice to call model on controller (view) in django?

Tags: django

The question is not only about django though...I know the MVC mantra that claims that controllers should be thin and models fat. But speaking of the case I'm dealing with right now. I neeed to do such a simple thing as get an object from the DB by its `id` which means I have to use something like `MyModel.objects.get(id=object_id)`, I would like to put this code into `MyView` (read controller) but I'm not sure if it's a good idea. On the other hand serializers are for serializing/deserializing data and all calls to models should be inside views. Is it right?

Comment: Of course you would put that in the view. How else would you get the model instance? That doesn't contradict the thin controllers thing at all.

Comment: If you take some time to browse the very comprehensive collection of official docs and tutorials at https://www.djangoproject.com/, you will see that this is standard practice.